# What is the value of iCloud.com if 2FA requires your device?

Tags: icloud, two-factor-authentication

It would seem that the point of iCloud.com and its web apps is to provide access to your content on the go, when for whatever reason, you don’t have access to your device itself.

But if logging into the website requires you to first authenticate yourself *with the device*, then what is the point of the website?

Of course if you have your device handy — then you wouldn’t need the website...

How is this not a glaring oversight by Apple?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.  Logging in to 2 different places to verify your identity is the '2' in 2FA.  The point of iCloud.com is to give you another way to access your info but it's not only, or even largely, because you don't have access to your device.  If you're asking why Apple does this then your question could be closed as off-topic so you might want to rephrase it to focus on the actual problem you're having.

Comment: Having another way to access your info is great, but not if accessing it requires you to be carrying a device which already has access to it. That is the point.

Comment: How is it any sort of "oversight"?  You automatically assume that accessing the content via the "device" is always preferable, without specifying what the "device" is.

Comment: @bigmapidea But then it wouldn't be two-factor authentication. It would simply be a login with a password. If that doesn't work for you then you need to find a less secure way to access your data and don't use icloud.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you access a 2FA-protected iCloud account on any device you've chosen to use with 2FA, you must provide the correct credentials *with that device* to assure iCloud that it is indeed *the device you've selected to receive 2FA authentication*. You are then offered the choice of ignoring future requests for authentication on that device for some duration of time. Every so often, you must re-authenticate with the 2FA credentials to reassert your identity. Does this help?